# Where is the Ruby interpreter located?

Tags: ruby, interpreter, interpreted-language

I'm using Ruby 1.8.7 on OS X. **Where is the Ruby interpreter located?** My goal is to learn more about Ruby, interpreted languages and interpreting/parsing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can run `which ruby` to find out where the ruby is that will execute if you type `ruby` in the Terminal.

If you want to find more information out about the executable, you can run:

```
$ ls -l $(which ruby)
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  76 Nov  8 12:56 /usr/bin/ruby -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby
```

That is, execute `which ruby`, and pass the results of that into `ls -l`, which will show you that it's actually a symlink to the binary in the Ruby framework. You can also use `file` to find out what kind of file it is:

```
$ file $(which ruby)
/usr/bin/ruby: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/usr/bin/ruby (for architecture x86_64):    Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/usr/bin/ruby (for architecture i386):  Mach-O executable i386
```

If you want to make sure you execute the ruby that is in the user's path from a script, instead of hardcoding where Ruby is, you can use the following interpreter directive at the top of your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

This works because pretty much all modern systems have an executable at `/usr/bin/env` which will execute the utility that you pass to it based on your path; so instead of hardcoding `/usr/bin/ruby` into your script, you can let `env` search your path for you.

Answer (score 3):

`whereis ruby` in a Terminal window will tell you

Comment: Generally, `which` is more reliable than `whereis`. `which` will find the one that's actually in your path, while `whereis` will look in certain standard directories; if you have non-standard directories in your path (like `/opt/local/bin` for MacPorts), `whereis` won't find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You should find it under 
`System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby`
and symlinked to 
`/usr/bin/ruby`.

running `which ruby` will give you the exact location of the ruby being used if there are one or more implementations on your system.